# OAuth2 scope for requesting access to a specific pre-existing file with the Google Drive API

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, scope, google-drive-api

I would like to request authorization to read and write to a specific file (and its children) in the user's Google Drive.

I would use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope but from my knowledge you can only create new files that you have access to. I have also looked at the other scopes but none of them or any combination of them allow me to do this from what I can tell.

Is there a way to modify this scope or use another scope to achieve this?

Comment: It is restricted for very good reasons, if you could manipulate files you do not own or have created, then this would be a very bad security leak!

Comment: How can only having access to one directory be a security leak?

Comment: Access to a user's preexisting files? Not a security threat?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, your application's users have a file (or directory of files) already existing in Google Drive that they want to use in your application.  You only need access to the files the user specifies, so the general "drive" permission is overkill/dangerous.

I've used the [Google File Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) for this.  Your app can open the file picker within your application and when the user chooses to open the file(s) using the picker, your application will be granted the "drive.file" scope for just those files (the actual specific permissions can be configured as part of setting up the picker).

This lets the users browse/search their Google Drive to find the item without your app needing access to their full Drive to just to let them pick the file they want.  Not sure if the picker has the ability to pick a directory and and grant permission to all its children though.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth), Google has a list of scopes for the Drive API and a description for each.

> **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file**
>
> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File
>   authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the
>   user deauthorizes the app.

I think you might need

> **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive**
>
> Full, permissive scope to access all of a user's files, excluding the
>   Application Data folder.

As for the scopes, you can have multiple scopes to achieve the required authorization for your app. In the scope parameter in your configuration, add the additional scopes by separating them with a space in the same string.

Comment: I've looked at all of these and none are close to my needs except drive.file which is close but not what I need. A combination wouldn't help either.

Comment: Why it wouldn't help? I think you need the list file api call, but to view preexisting files you need the full drive scope. Either way, if you want to use the more restrictive scopes, you will have to undergo a security assessment from Google

Comment: This answer doesn't help me.

Comment: What have you tried and where is the actual error in your approach?